# Delegate jquery - get parent container

Tags: jquery

I want to select all `p` elements in .section container, but just in the one that contains the a.open link that has been clicked

```
$('.section').delegate('a.open', "click", function(){
    $(this).parent().filter('p').show(); //I want to select all `p` elements in .section container, but just in th one that containts the a.open link that has been clicked
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `find` instead of `filter`. `filter('p')` selects all `<p>` elements in the collection of `$(this).parent()`, which is at most one element. `find('p')` selects all descendants of `$(this).parent()`, which are `<p>` elements.

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass the delegateTarget as context (delegateTarget is a property of the event object which is passed to handler function and is the DOM element which "Handles" the delegation

```
$('.section').delegate('a.open', "click", function(e){
    $('p', e.delegateTarget).show()
    //This means show all <p> elements in the context defined by e.delegateTarget
})
```

look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jWYKv/

Comment: Using jQuery 1.5.2 I've had to use $('div.my-class', e.liveFired).show();

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) (goes up the tree and stops at the first `.section`), [Find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (finds all descendants filtered by the given selector)

```
$('.section').delegate('a.open', "click", function(){
    $(this).closest('.section').find('p').show();
})
```

Comment: This works, but it's not that efficent (you have to go up and down the dom).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents('th:first').find('p').show();
```

What about that ?

Edit: misinterpreted your explaination of the problem

```
$(this).parents('.section:first').find('p').show();
```

Comment: Why do you think the elements are inside a table header cell?

Comment: he said "just in the th that contains the link". I could have misinterpreted, but its easy enough to change the selector if thats the case

Comment: The text is actually *"[...]but just in th one that [...]"* which I assume is just a typo and should be *"[...] but just in the one that [...]"*.

Comment: Fair enough, i just read it differently. However i do see your point now. Code changed